# How to create a combo box column using raw values of a data table in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, datagridview, combobox

My goal would be to modify an already existing data grid column into a combo box (drop down list) using C#. The grid is populated using a data table.
So basically, let's say the column "Profile" has following string values={"X", "Y", "Z", "W"}. The "new" column "Profile" should have then for each cell a drop down list containing the beforementioned string values. However, the column "Profile" should not be a new one but should be the modified version of the already existing "profile" column. So ideally, the algorithm or function should follow these steps:

1. Search for the Column I want to transform into a drop down list
2. Look trough all the rows and collect all the unique values
3. Substitute the column with the new one containing for each cell the values using a dropdown.
   So at the end the number of columns should remain the same.
   Thank you in advance for your precious help.
   Cheers!!

So far the only I managed to do something was by creating a new column and hiding/Deleting the old one. But doing so, it would be a very inefficient way as if 1 Mil rows exist then all the values need to be copied over.

Comment: That's not the way to do it. You can't change one column type into another column type. You would have to remove the existing column and add a new one, so you may as well not add the original one in the first place. What you should do is add the combo box column in the designer and set the `DataPropertyName` property so it knows which column of the data source to bind to. You can add the other columns too or just that one. Populate your `DataTable`, get the distinct values from that column, add them to the `Items` list, then bind your `DataTable` to the grid.

Comment: See [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?541476) for more info.